# Como fazer uma regex que ignore caracteres não-alfanuméricos?

Tags: regex

Por exemplo:uma regex que ache correpondencia na string "moeda" mas que também ache correspondencia na string (m,.o,e.d...a). Ou seja ela ignora caracteres não alfanuméricos independente da posição ou da quantidade.

OBS:JA SEI FAZER DA SEGUINTE FORMA MAS A IDÉIA É SÓ DIGITAR 1 VEZ.

```
 #=\W*
```

> m#o#e#d#a

Comment: É uma string apenas ou quer capturar múltiplas palavras em uma string e separa-las?

Answer (score 3):

Se entendi com o termo "capturar", o que você quer é remover os caracteres **não alfanuméricos**, use `replace`, a regex de negação deve ser assim:

```
[^a-z0-9]
```

O sinal de `^` dentro de `[...]` faz negar qualquer caractere, então o replace vai remover todos que não são os que tiverem dentro `[^....]`

Em JavaScript deve usar com o modificador `global` chamado `/.../g` e com o `/.../i` se necessitar de case-insensitive, exemplo:

```js
var str = "m,.o,e.d...a";
var resposta = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, "");
console.log(resposta);
```

Em PHP seria assim, com `preg_replace`:

```
$str = "m,.o,e.d...a";
$resposta = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#', '', $str);

var_dump($resposta);
```

Exemplo online no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/t83PEz)

**Nota:**

É importante perceber que se quiser adicionar mais caráteres para **não serem** removidos, como espaços, basta adicionar dentro de `[^....]`, exemplo que "captura" os alfanumericos e espaços:

```js
var str = "m,.o,e.d...a ,.n,.a,. ,.,.c,.a,.r,.t,.e,.i,.r,.a";
var resposta = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, "");
console.log(resposta);
```

---

### Capturar em um array

Se de fato você quer capturar, então o correto é usar `.match` em JavaScript e `preg_match` em PHP, a regx também mudaria, para algo um pouco mais complexo, considerando que é uma string com diferentes palavras e você queira capturar todas, então tem que ser algo assim:

```
(^|\s)([a-z0-9]*[^\s]*)(\s|$)
```

Exemplo em JavaScript:

```js
var str = "m,.o,e.d...a ,.n,.a,. ,.,.c,.a,.r,.t,.e,.i,.r,.a";
var respostas = str.match(/(^|\s)([^\s]+?)(\s|$)/gi, "");
var allowAN = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;

for (var i = 0, j = respostas.length; i < j; i++) {
    respostas[i] = respostas[i].trim().replace(allowAN, "");
}

console.log(respostas);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use apenas `\w+` isso vai casar todos os caracteres no intervalode e `A-Za-z0-9` uma ou mais vezes.

```
console.log('m#o#e#d#a'.match(/\w+/g));
console.log('m,.o,e.d...a'.match(/\w+/g));
```

Comment: a questão é que eu quero capturar uma determinada string, não genérica, ou seja, eu quero que ele capture a sequencia m-o-e-d-a independente de caracteres alfa-numéricos entre os digitos.

Comment: @FelipePadilha vc está usando alguma linguagem ou editor de texto especifico?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize essa expressão regular:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]
```

[Teste aqui](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: a questão é que eu quero capturar uma determinada string, não genérica, ou seja, eu quero que ele capture a sequencia m-o-e-d-a independente de caracteres alfa-numéricos entre os digitos.

Comment: @FelipePadilha você quer dizer caracteres NÃO alfa-numéricos certo?

Comment: @FelipePadilha por exemplo: em uma string "mKoKeKdKa" não deve dar match, porém em uma string como "$m!o#e@d(a" deve dar match certo?

Comment: sim, caracteres não-alfanumericos, perdão

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho a certeza se entendi o pedido, mas

```
var s="m.o...e,!d--a";
console.log(s.replace(/\W/g,"").match(/moeda/) ? "y":"n")
```

(ou seja, retirar primeiro os "não letra" e depois procurar "moeda") pode
ser usado para detetar se uma string contem "moeda".

Answer (score 0):

**Não é possível fazer o que você quer utilizando regex.**
Em uma expressão regular você deve designar o que quer encontrar através de uma sequencia lógica de tokens e quantifiers.
No seu caso você quer buscar uma sequencia determinada, **porém não quer utilizar quantifiers e nem os tokens para ignorar o que está entre a sequencia** (como mencionou no comentário dessa resposta)
Ou seja, o único jeito para isso seria adicionando uma flag global na regex como `\x` (que ignora espaços em branco nas buscas), entretanto não existe tal flag para o seu caso, pois o resultado que você quer alcançar pode ser obtido através de tokens e quantifiers, eliminando a necessidade de criação de uma flag pra isso.

O resultado que você quer pode ser obtido somente através dessa RegEx:

```
(m\W*o\W*e\W*d\W*a)
```

[Você pode testa-la aqui](https://regex101.com/r/1ee6eE/2)

**Explicação**

- `()` Representa o grupo de captura que sua regex irá retornar caso a condição for satisfeira
- `m`  é o caractere que deve ser encontrado primeiro para iniciar o "match" da regex
- `\W*`representa que pode haver entre 0 e infinitos caracteres que sejam não-alfanuméricos
- `o` outro caractere que deve estar após o "m" para que a condição seja satisfeita
- `\W*` tem o mesmo efeito do anterior
- e assim segue a regex até que encontre `e` `d` e `a` mesmo que contenham caracteres não-alfanuméricos entre eles

Comment: Sim, dessa forma dá certo, mas eu queria uma forma que eu não tenha que digitar entre todo caracter alfanumérico, a idéia era digitar somente uma vez

Comment: @FelipePadilha não entendi, o que você não quer digitar?

Comment: não quero ter de digitar \W*, ou este grupo nomeado, entre todo caracter não alfa numérico

Comment: entre todo caraccter *alfa numérico

Comment: infelizmente não há outro jeito de se chegar a isso, não existe nenhum flavour de regex que contenha uma flag global que mude o método de busca como você quer, você pode ler a minha explicação na resposta para ter uma noção melhor do porque @FelipePadilha